# Generate MD5 Hash of String in JRuby

Tags: ruby, hash, md5, jruby, hashcode

How can I generate `MD5 hash` of a `String` in `JRuby`?

```
String = 'device S6'
```

Comment: You don't `need` lots of `backticks` to surround every `possibly` programming-related `term`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating an md5 hash of a number, string, array, or hash in Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6461812/creating-an-md5-hash-of-a-number-string-array-or-hash-in-ruby)

Answer (score 2):

This is a quick jirb session:

```
>> require 'digest/md5'
=> true
>> md5 = Digest::MD5.new
=> #<Digest::MD5: d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e>
>> md5.hexdigest 'device S6'
=> "0bdf995668120bcb78bfb125995d54e1"
```

This should get you going...