# Order of keys in a JSON object converted to a Ruby Hash with JSON.parse

Tags: ruby, json

In Javascript, object keys are not ordered, whereas in Ruby, [Hashes enumerate their values in the order that the corresponding keys were inserted](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html).

In practice, it seems to be the case that when converting JSON objects to Ruby Hashes, keys in the Ruby Hash are in the order in which they were written in the JSON data, e.g.:

```
irb(main):002:0> JSON.parse('{"a": 1, "b": 2}')
=> {"a"=>1, "b"=>2}

irb(main):005:0> JSON.parse('{"b": 1, "a": 2}')
=> {"b"=>1, "a"=>2}
```

Can I rely on the assumption that it will always be the case?

I'd think so, because when parsing JSON, I guess the parser is inserting keys as it discovers them, but I couldn't find any reference on the subject.

Comment: It's not in the documentation, so while it may work reliably _now_, it will not necessarily be reliable moving forward. Why are you relying on key order in the first place when javascript keys aren't ordered?

Answer (score 0):

Rely on the assumption, you can. Ruby does keep track of the order of keys.

Answer (score 0):

The key order is preserved, based on insert, at least in newer versions of Ruby. From the [Ruby 2.6.3 Hash documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Hash.html)

> Hashes enumerate their values in the order that the corresponding keys were inserted

This is the case for (as far as I can tell) all currently supported Ruby versions (even older 2.x versions that are unsupported are documented as above)